# Can I use component name in lower case in jsx

Tags: reactjs, jsx

[Docs of react](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components) say

> React's JSX uses the upper vs. lower case convention to distinguish between local component classes and HTML tags.

But it looks like it works with both cases now

```
function foo(div) {
  <div.Form/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`div.Form` is a reference to a variable and because of that interpreted as a component class.

```
function bar(myElement) {
  return <myElement />;
}
```

The code above would not use the `myElement` class you passed in, but interpret `myElement` as a HTML tag.

This is how it works now, using Babel to transform JSX:

**Components**

- `<MyComponent />`
- `<myLibrary.MyComponent />`
- `<myLibrary.myComponent />` (don't do this, component classes should use capital letters)
- `<MyLibrary.MyComponent />` (don't do this, MyLibrary is probably not a class)

**HTML**

- `<div />`
- `<my-component />`
- `<myComponent />` (don't do this, HTML is case insensitive, lowercase
- `<My-Component />` (don't do this, HTML is case insensitive, lowercase is a convention)